# Multiplicity of the simple $R$-module $M$ in the semisimple ring $R$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I'm confused about the conclusion of Wedderburn's structure theorem for semisimple rings.
Let's consider the special case where $R=M^n$ as modules for some simple module $M$.
Wedderburn's theorem says that $R=M_n(D)$ for $D=\text{End}_R(M)^{o}$.
Thus, $R=(D^n)^n$ as modules. I see that $D^n$ is a simple $R$-module.

So, since all simple $R$-modules appear in the decomposition of the $R$-module $R$ as a direct sum of simple $R$-modules, I conclude that $M\cong D^n$. In particular, $M$ can be seen as a $D$-module and $n=\dim_D(M)$ (we can talk about dimension since $D$ is a division ring by Schur's lemma).

My question:

> Remembering that $D=\text{End}_R(M)^{o}$, is there a natural way to view $M$ as a $D$-module? What is the ring homomorphism $\text{End}_R(M)^o\rightarrow\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ that describes the action of $D$ on $M$?

There is an obvious way to view $M$ as an $\text{End}_R(M)$-module since $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a subring of $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$, but since $D$ is the opposite ring relative to $\text{End}_R(M)$ and not $\text{End}_R(M)$ itself, I am confused.

**Motivation**: I'd like to be able to look at a semisimple ring and ask how many times a simple module $M$ appears in its decomposition by looking at $M$ as an $\text{End}_R(M)^o$-module and computing the dimension.

Comment: The opposite just means to write homomorphisms on the other side. In other words, if you normally write homomorphisms on the left, then M is a right End(M)^o module.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: But isn't it the case that we saw that $M \cong D^n$ as left-modules (assuming I'm starting with a decomposition of $R$ as a *left* module). I see that $M$ is a right $\text{End}_R(M)^o$-module, but is it really what we got here?

Comment: $M \cong D^n$ as left $R$-modules and right $D$-modules. Don't leave out the ring or you will get confused. $M$ is indecomposable as a left $R$-module.

Comment: You may also want to use a ring whose left and right modules are distinguishable as abelian groups in order to keep things straight. Triangular rings can work well for this.

Comment: Triangular rings as in triangular matrices over a field?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} r & m \\ 0 & s \end{bmatrix}$ for r in a ring R, s in a ring S, and m in a left-R right-S bimodule M. This is one of the nicer ways to construct rings whose left and right hand behaviors are very different. Take R=Z, M=Q, S=Q for instance and I believe the ring has finite cardinality nonzero left modules but all nonzero right modules are infinite (or something similar).

Comment: @JackSchmidt I like this suggestion, but it does stray a bit away from the OP's desire to study semisimple rings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abelian group $M$ has a right $D$ module structure iff it has a left $D^{op}$ module structure.

If $M$ is a left $R$ module, then there is the natural operation of $D$ on the right of $M$. Moving over to the opposite ring, this becomes a left $D^{op}$ structure on $M$.

---

Here's the way to see where the dimension $n$ comes from for a *simple Artinian ring*. It's easy to prove that all simple left $R$ modules are isomorphic to each other, so you can start by decomposing $R$ into minimal left ideals. Suppose $R=\oplus_{i=1}^n S$ is a direct sum of simple left $R$ modules. Then $D=End(_RS)$ is a division ring, and since $R^{op}\cong End(_RR)=End(\oplus_{i=1}^n S)\cong M_n(End(_RS))=M_n(D)\cong M_n(D^{op})^{op}$. Then we have that $M_n(D^{op})\cong R$ as rings. But clearly ($D^{op})^n$ is a simple left $M_n(D^{op})$ $(=R!)$ module, therefore $S\cong (D^{op})^n$ as left $R$ modules.

Notice that $D^{op}$ is embedded as the constant diagonal matrices in $R$, and multiplication by these matrices is the same as looking at $(D^{op})^n$ as a left $D^{op}$ vector space. Switching to the right, it is a right $D$ vector space.

---

Now for general semisimple rings, you first just split the ring into simple rings. Then it's easy to show that the simple left modules are just exactly the simple modules for each simple ring in that factorization. So, you can reduce the general case to finitely many cases like the one above.

Comment: Thanks. So, if understand correctly, it is true to say the $n$ is the dimension of $M$ over $\text{End}_R(M)$ as a left module, right?

Comment: @Itai Where is $n$ coming from... your post?

Comment: Yes, $n$ from my post. It is the number of number of occurences of $M$ in $R$ in the decomposition to simple left $R$-modules.

Comment: You write $R\cong \text{End}(_RR)$. Isn't it $R\cong \text{End}(R_R)$?

Comment: @Itai Oh yeah, you're right, I mixed up sides :) I'll fix it..

Comment: @Itai I had to make the modification that $R^{op}\cong M_n(D)$, but then we are helped by the fact that the matrix ring is isomorphic to its opposite ring (via the transposition map) :)

Comment: In the new notation, $M_n(D)\cong R$ should be $M_n(D^{op})\cong R$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Itai Yeah, I just wasn't done yet :)

Comment: Being a module is a structure, not a property. You should say "having a right $D$-module structure is the same thing as having a left $D^{op}$-module structure."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sure, that is clearer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still confused about one point: Showing that $S\cong (D^{op})^n$ as left $R$-modules is OK. But then, *why* are they also isomorphic as right $D^{op}$-modules?

Comment: @Itai You're right, I wasn't clear enough. How about now?

Comment: Now it's perfect. At least in my head. Hopefully in the answer's text too. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Itai I'm working from memory (which is not always the most reliable thing). Thanks for proofreading my work.

Comment: I read it again and it all looks correct, but it brings me again to my original question: We start with the left $R$-module $S$ and conclude that $S$ is also a right module over $D=\text{End}_R(M)$. Can we describe the $D$ action on $M$? For that we need a ring homomorphism $D \rightarrow \text{End}(M)^{op}$ (the opposite is there because we're looking at a right action).

Comment: @Itai Given our left $D^{op}$ action, you get the $D$ action for free by: $m\cdot d:=dm$ for $d\in D^{op}$. Doesn't this amount to just taking $D^{op}\to End(M)$ and looking upon it as $D\to End(M)^{op}$?

Comment: This is not the part that confuses me, so let's take a step back. Consider the left $D^{op}$ action. Can you describe it as a ring homomorphism $D^{op}\rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$? Where would you send $\varphi\in D^{op}$?

Comment: Maybe it's not so easy to describe explicitly because the isomorphism $S\cong (D^{op})^n$ is not given explicitly.

Comment: @Itai *Can we describe the D action on M?* The "original" $D$ action on $M$ hasn't changed since the beginning: $m\cdot d:=d(m)$. I think the left $D^{op}$ action matches the original right $D$ action, but yeah, I didn't show that. Until now I've been focused only on showing the dimension for you :)

Comment: Let's focus on the "original" $D$ action. You are describing it as a right action. I don't understand how this is a right action. Take $d_1,d_2\in D=\text{End}(_RS)$. Now $m\cdot (d_1\circ d_2)=(d_1\circ d_2)(m)=d_1(d_2(m))$, but $(m\cdot d_1)\cdot d_2=d_2(m\cdot d_1)=d_2(d_1(m))$.

Comment: @Itai You're right: I never properly fixed the side issue :( If $M$ is a right $R$ module, then $d\cdot m:=d(m)$ properly describes a left $D$ module action. When you are using a left module $M$, then this results in a $D^{op}$ action on the right. Sorry... I learned it with right $R$ modules and winding up making these mistakes. Later today I'll have to spend some time trying to sort it out again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to do so too.

Comment: I think that the correct ring homomorphism $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}\rightarrow \text{End}(_{\mathbb{Z}}M)$ is defined as follows: Decompose $1\in R$ as a sum of orthogonal idempotents: $1=e_1+\dots+e_n$. Send $d\in\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$ to the endomorphism of multiplication on the right by $d(e_1)+\dots+d(e_n)$. Hopefully that's correct. If it is - is there a nicer way to describe it?

Comment: @Itai Not sure... I suggest we think about it. Btw, I can't find any error about sides in the post. I think I was just mistaken about a right $D$ structure via evaluation. I think the two things we were focused on were a left and right $D^{op}$ structures. I think I'm going to go review it slowly rather than continue to work it out in the comments

Comment: I explained my new ideas as a new answer because it is too long for a comment.

Comment: @rschwieb Could you please expand on the last paragraph? How do we reduce the general case into finitely many cases?

Comment: @AgentSmith Given a finite product of rings, the left ideals are of the form "cartesian product of left ideals of the component rings."  The minimal left ideals are the ones of the form "all zero except for one, which is a minimal left ideal in that component."  In the case of simple Artinian rings, each component only has one isotype of simple left module, so there are only as many simple left modules for the product ring as there are simple component rings.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to describe the left $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$-module structure of $M$.

Wedderburn's theorem gives us and isomorphism:
$R\cong\text{End}(_RR)^{op}\cong\text{End}(_RM^n)^{op}\cong M_n(\text{End}(_RM))^{op}\cong
M_n(\text{End}(_RM)^{op})$ (the first isomorphism takes $r\in R$ to the endomorphism of right multiplication by $r$ and the last one is transposition).

The diagonal injection $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}\hookrightarrow M_n(\text{End}(_RM)^{op})$ gives any $M_n(\text{End}(_RM)^{op})$-module a structure of an $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$-module.

Wedderburn's isomorphism gives a way to look at any $R$-module as an $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$-module by the composite map $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}\hookrightarrow M_n(\text{End}(_RM)^{op})\cong R$. To describe it more concretely, we need to follow Wedderburn's isomorphism backwards. Since we're only looking at the image of the diagonal injection $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}\hookrightarrow M_n(\text{End}(_RM)^{op})$, the transposition does nothing. We will allow ourselves to represent elements of $R$ using coordinates corresponding to the module decomposition $R=M^n$. So, $d\in\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$ maps to the element $r\in R$ such that for any $(m_1,\dotsc,m_n)\in M^n$ it holds that $(m_1,\dotsc,m_n)r=(d(m_1),\dotsc,d(m_n))$. Choose $(e_1,\dotsc,e_n)\in M^n$ representing $1\in R$ and get $r=(d(e_1),\dotsc,d(e_n))$.

As I described it, looking at the $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$-structure of $M$ is not a very useful way to determine $n$ because to understand it, one already need to know the module decomposition $R=M^n$, which includes knowing $n$.

Maybe adding additional structure to $R$ (like making it an algebra over a field) would make it possible to understand the dimension of $M$ over $\text{End}(_RM)^{op}$ without actually understanding the action itself. To do so, we'd probably have to check some of the homomorphisms above are algebra homomorphisms.

The idea behind the previous paragraph is that if $A$ is a division algebra over a field $k$ and $M$ is a module over $A$ then we get an induced $k$-module structure of $M$. It is then enough to understand the $k$-module structure of $A$ and the induced $k$-module structure of $M$ and use the equtation $[M:k]=[M:A]\cdot [A:k]$ to extract $n=[M:A]$.

To justify looking at $k \subset A \subset M$ as a tower of subspaces, we need to note that the algebra action homomorphism $k \hookrightarrow A$ coincides with $k \hookrightarrow \text{End}(_AM)^{op} \rightarrow A$.